# How to leave cells blank when their value is 0 or does not exist in formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How to tell the macro to leave the cell blank and not put a zero if the value of the cell is 0 or does not exist? In other types of formulas, I just added ,""-"")" at the end but in this case it does not work...

```
.Range("Z" & i & ":AB" & i).Formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",$Y" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastrow & ")/" & dic(.Range("Y" & i).Value)
```

An example of a working occasion is this

```
.Range("AD" & i).Formula = "=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$" & lastrow & ",MATCH($Y" & i & ",$D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",0))=0,Z" & i & ",""-"")"
```

Comment: Try to use "" that means Blank or `If .Range("I2:" &"I"& i)<>"" Then` and input actions and `End If` That means if the cell in range is different from blank, then do something

Comment: It is not working.. I have tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula in the example that does not work does not include the same conditional as your example of a working formula.

Your second formula is, essentially, "if this value is 0, then do X". Your first formula only has the SUMIF formula, it does not evaluate if the value returned is 0.

You should add the same logic to your SUMIF formula, to get the same result. Specifically, you need to ad an "IF" formula to this. Here's an example I have not tested, but should be more or less accurate.

```
.Range("Z" & i & ":AB" & i).Formula = "=if(SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",$Y" 
& i & ",E$2:E$" & lastRow & ")/" & dic(.Range("Y" & i).Value) & "=0,""""," & 
"SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastRow & ",$Y" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastRow & ")/" & 
dic(.Range("Y" & i).Value) & ")"
```

This will build the *formula* to check for 0s. If you want VBA to check for 0s, that will be a different solution.

Update for your comment:

I think this is what you're looking for, although I think your formula has an error in it.

```
"=IF($Z$2:$Z$" & lastRow & "*$AC$2:$AC" & lastRow & "=0,""-""," & "$Z$2:$Z$" 
& lastRow & "*$AC$2:$AC" & lastRow & ")"
```

Comment: .Range("X" & i).Formula = "=IF($Z$2:$Z$" & lastrow & "*$AC$2:$AC" & lastrow & " & "=0,""-"")" and finally one last conversion for this one.. do you know how to do this one too?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many information missing I think, but if I understand that you want to use VBA to add a built-in function into your cell (`SUMIF`) but you want this `SUMIF` to return `""` instead of `0` (which is the normal return type, since the function is supposed to return a number), then what you can do is to build a nested function saying that if the result of your function is different than zero then you write that result, otherwise you write "":

```
.Range("Z" & i & ":AB" & i).Formula = "=IF(SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",$Y" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastrow & ")/" & dic(.Range("Y" & i).Value) & "<> 0, SUMIF($D$2:$D$" & lastrow & ",$Y" & i & ",E$2:E$" & lastrow & ")/" & dic(.Range("Y" & i).Value), "")
```

... but if you give us more information there's probably a better way to get the result (probably a user-function instead of the built-in `SUMIF` directly put in the cell).